Can't find the cause of a has many through association error
I'm building a token provisioning API that enforces quotas. When I try to create a Token, I keep getting the following error, and I cannot figure out why:
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot 
modify association 'Token#limits' because the source reflection class 'Limit' 
is associated to 'Resource' via :has_many.

I have distilled this down to an MVP Rails 7.1.3.4 app on Ruby 3.3.3.
# db/schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema[7.1].define(version: 2024_06_28_175444) do
  create_table "limits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "plan_id", null: false
    t.integer "resource_id", null: false
    t.integer "budget", null: false
    t.index ["plan_id"], name: "index_limits_on_plan_id"
    t.index ["resource_id"], name: "index_limits_on_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "plans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
  end

  create_table "resources", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
  end

  create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "plan_id", null: false
    t.index ["plan_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_plan_id"
  end

  create_table "tokens", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "subscription_id", null: false
    t.integer "resource_id", null: false
    t.index ["resource_id"], name: "index_tokens_on_resource_id"
    t.index ["subscription_id"], name: "index_tokens_on_subscription_id"
  end

end

class Plan < ApplicationRecord; end

class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :limits
end

class Limit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :resource
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
end

class Token < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :resource

  has_one :plan, through: :subscription
  has_many :limits, ->(token) { where(plan: token.plan) }, through: :resource

  validate :limits_apply

  private

  def limits_apply
    errors.add(:limits, "no limits apply to this token") unless limits.length > 0
  end
end

# tests/token_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class TokenTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @resource = Resource.create name: 'Widget'
    @plan = Plan.create name: 'Bronze'
    @subscription = Subscription.create plan: @plan
    @limit = Limit.create plan: @plan, resource: @resource, budget: 5
  end

  test '.create!' do
    assert_nothing_raised do
      Token.create!(resource: @resource, subscription: @subscription)
    end
  end
end

$ rails test
Running 1 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 49750

# Running:

E

Error:
TokenTest#test_.create!:
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot 
modify association 'Token#limits' because the source reflection class 'Limit' 
is associated to 'Resource' via :has_many.
    test/models/token_test.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <class:TokenTest>'
    test/models/token_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:TokenTest>'


bin/rails test test/models/token_test.rb:11



Finished in 0.043282s, 23.1043 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

This issue arises only when the :quotas relation on the Token model is loaded before save. If I change the :quotas relation to a plain instance method, the issue disappears:
class Token < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  # has_many :limits, ->(token) { where(plan: token.plan) }, through: :resource
  def limits
    resource.limits.where(plan: plan)
  end

  # ...
end

$ rails test
Running 1 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 56588

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.049800s, 20.0803 runs/s, 20.0803 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

What am I missing in regards to my association definitions to make this work?

A resource may have more than one limit for a given plan. For example, a subscription to the "Bronze" plan might afford you "5 Widgets per Day" and "30 Widgets per Month". Both limits apply, so a token has many limits that it must adhere to.

Not directly related but you very likely should use size instead of length in Token #limits_apply. Length applies only to loaded records in memory, size will do a count if the assocation has not yet been loaded.

I’m using length here on purpose to force the association to be loaded and surface the issue here.

The actual business logic in my application is a bit more complex as it actually examines the limits to ensure you haven’t exceeded them. But in this example, I only need to load the association to replicate the issue.

The error is raised by ensure_mutable. It appears this has to do with an attempt to save the limits through record in save_through_record (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L82) called by insert_record (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L31)

Why this is occurring I cannot say and it might be worth opening an issue ticket with the rails team to see if you can get a more comprehensive answer.

Adding autosave: false to my has-many-through association resolved this issue.

In the Token model, setting the quotas association to not autosave resolved this issue:
class Token < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :quotas, 
    ->(token) { where plan: token.plan }, 
    through: :resource, 
    autosave: false

end

Thank you @engineersmnky for the tip!
